# Memcache on kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, memcached

I have a `spring boot` api running on `google cloud kubernetes cluster`, I wanna have a caching server to use for my api so I thought to use `memcache`.

I tried two ways of doing it:

1. I downloaded the `memcache` from the google launcher which is basically deploying an instance of `memcache` on a vm. And then I assigned an external `IP` to my vm, whitelisted my ip to try it locally and ofc opened the port `11211` (the default one). For the client side I used, [this guy](https://github.com/sixhours-team/memcached-spring-boot), specified the ip address but I still get connection cancelled : `java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Cancelled` and the doc is bad so I could find anything that helps.
2. I decided to try another way, which is following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploying-memcached-on-kubernetes-engine) and now I have the `memcached` cluster but I don't know how to consume these pods from my other cluster or should the pods be on the same cluster i have the api running on?

I would appreciate any help, this is my first encounter with the global caching.

Comment: memcached is an application cache, not an http cache- is that what you're looking for? As an application cache it should definitely run in close network proximity to the application, on the same cluster. When you create a Deployment and a Service for it, you can use the dns name created by the Service in your application config, to let your application know where to find the memcached instance(s).

Comment: so I can't have a memcache shared between my instances? like memcache for appengine, where it could be shared between all the instances, that's what I want to achieve but with app deployed on Kubernetes

Comment: Yes, that's what it's for- but in the context of your #2 above, you don't want to have a separate memcached cluster. You want memcached to be running inside of your existing cluster. So you can follow those same instructions for deploying memcached with helm, but just do it on the cluster you already have rather than starting by creating a new cluster.

Comment: hum, what about the first solution? to have a memcached vm and connect to it?

Comment: You want memcached to be on the same network as the application, as proximate to the application as possible. Standing up a random VM and configuring ACLs doesn't give you that. Try first running it directly on a kubernetes cluster worker node.

Comment: One issue that i'm wondering about, if I run it directly on a kubernetes node, how can I test that locally to see if it works first?

Comment: For testing purposes you can assign a pod to the node on which a memcached is running: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out based on Jonah Benton's advice.

It was actually pretty simple, i used [this tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/memcached-docker/blob/master/1/README.md) to create a new pod running `memcached` in my cluster and then I used [this](https://github.com/sixhours-team/memcached-spring-boot) client to connect on it and it worked like a charm!

Hope it helps someone.